# String Replace + Camel Case

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert **"do_not_honor"** to **"Do Not Honor"**. I tried with **str_replace** and **ucwords** but all I get is "Do not honor". Any suggestions? Regards.

Comment: echo ucwords(str_replace('_',' ','do_not_honor'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo ucwords(str_replace('_',' ','do_not_honor'));
```